# Raise Child_Exception/OSError: [Errno 2] No such file error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working with [WARC Tools](http://mandal.ca/web.cgi/HelpOnWarcTools), a python library for working with WARC files. I've installed everything and it all seems to work except for the last command. While I suspect many of you may not have worked with this tool, perhaps you can make sense of the error message for me.

When I run this command:

`python /path/filesdump.py filtered.warc` as per the documentation, I get this error message immediately:

```
html/811cac8c-7430-403b-96a4-7d77137b0d46.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/ianmilligan1/desktop/warc/warc-tools-mandel/filesdump.py", line 63, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/users/ianmilligan1/desktop/warc/warc-tools-mandel/filesdump.py", line 34, in main
    dump_archive(fh,name)
  File "/users/ianmilligan1/desktop/warc/warc-tools-mandel/filesdump.py", line 57, in dump_archive
    txt = record.filedump(content=True)
  File "/Users/ianmilligan1/Desktop/WARC/warc-tools-mandel/warctools/record.py", line 140, in filedump
    p = Popen(['lynx', '-dump', '-stdin', '-nomargins', '-unique_urls', '-width=120'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What's going on here? Where would you suggest I begin looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/), a command-line web browser that WARC Tools seems to require. That'll solve it.

What's going on is that warctools/record.py is calling lynx on line 140, and Python's subprocess library isn't finding the lynx executable so it throws an exception. They really ought to wrap the exception and provide a clearer message... Anyways. Try that and see if it fixes it.